# How to make html clock that doesn't display military time

Tags: javascript, html, time

I am working on a live html and javascript clock. This code is almost complete, but I do not want the clock to display military time,

**Here's what I've tried:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s + `<strong>a.m.</strong>`;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

function unMilitary() {
if (h = 13) {h = 1}
if (h = 14) {h = 2}
if (h = 15) {h = 3}
if (h = 16) {h = 4}
if (h = 17) {h = 5}
if (h = 18) {h = 6}
if (h = 19) {h = 7}
if (h = 20) {h = 8}
if (h = 21) {h = 9}
if (h = 22) {h = 10}
if (h = 23) {h = 11}
if (h = 24) {h = 12}
return h;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="time"></div>
<p>
(for those of you who are viewing this time in midday, it is displaying military time.)
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The `unMilitary` function isn't working, any suggestions?
Here is the code live in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey0u1tjd/1/).

Comment: Why are you hard coding `a.m.`?

Comment: Here are some options you may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556879/changing-the-1-24-hour-to-1-12-hour-for-the-gethours-method

Comment: @j08691 that was something I was going to fix later on please ignore that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid military time make if statement if hour more than 12 subtract 12 from hour

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();

    if(h >12) {
        h = h - 12;
        document.getElementById('ampm').innerHTML = "A.M";
    }
    document.getElementById('ampm').innerHTML = "P.M";

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s ;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="time" style="display: inline-block;"></div> <a id='ampm'></a>
<p>
for those of you who are viewing this time in midday, it is displaying 
military 
time. 
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (h = 13) {h = 1}
```

You are using the `=` operator in the condition `h = 13`, so the condition of the `if` statement assigns 13 to `h`. This is not what you want; use `h == 13`.

A simpler solution, however, would be:

```
if (h > 12) {
    return h - 12;
} else if (h == 0) { // you probably forgot about this case
    return 12;
} else {
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is easier way to deal with this, using native javascript and `toLocaleString` function and then splitting the result. Also you can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` which you have to call multiple times

```js
function getTimeCurrentTime() {
  let time = new Date();
  // toLocaleString in us format outputs 8/2/2019, 10:14:54 PM
  // we can then split that by comma and space and take last part of it
  return time.toLocaleString('en-US').split(', ')[1];
}

function updateCurrentTime() {
  let timeNode = document.getElementById('time');
  timeNode.innerHTML = getTimeCurrentTime();
}

setInterval(updateCurrentTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```